# What's a good terminal manager for OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, terminal

The `Terminal.app` application from OS X is quite good but it lack some functionality that I find really important like: ability to setup SSH profiles for connecting to different servers and ability to setup tunneling.

I know that there is a putty port for OS X but it uses X and is ugly. Is there any other alternative, preferably free?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Taken in mind that setting up a tunnel by your self [is really easy](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html), you may consider using iTerm2 as a replacement to Terminal.app.

[iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) features profiles, so you may connect to any SSH server instantly.

Advantages over Terminal.app:

http://www.iterm2.com/

If you still need to use a gui for tunneling, then you may use an app like:

[SSHTunnel](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/sshtunnel.html) or [SSH Tunnel Manager](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10128/ssh-tunnel-manager)

Comment: +1 for iTerm 2. I have recently moved completely over to iTerm 2.

Comment: Damn, I’m still using iTerm 0.10 and worry about the lack of updates. iTerm 2, you say?

Comment: iTerm 2 generally has nothing specific to do with SSH... iTerm 2 is absolutely fantastic, but it doesn't answer this question, at all.

Comment: @VxJasonxV: how does this not answer the question? iTerm 2 supports bookmarks for doing automatic ssh to hosts with a single click. And ssh tunneling is largely just calling ssh with `-D <port> -N` to open the tunnel on a port.

Comment: The implication is in the OPs reference to PuTTY. PuTTY doesn't make you issue raw forwarding commands. I gathered from the question that the OP wants an application to help him generate forwarding rules.

Comment: @VxJasonxV I guess I live by the teach-a-man-to-fish philosophy. You learn the ssh tunnel setup stuff once and you're set for life.

Comment: I wouldn't presume on the OPs methods of doing things. Also, there is more to learning ssh tunneling than the raw commands. The application and use of local, remote, or dynamic forwards are equally as relevant (and in some cases, difficult) as the command line flags.

Answer (score 7):

For SSH you just open a local Terminal and type `ssh host`.

You set up the configuration for each host in `~/.ssh/config` following the rules laid down in `man ssh`.

I guess I don't understand why anyone would need a graphical tool to set up SSH, a command-line program.

Comment: Because some people just don't have the association of configuration that we do.

Answer (score 1):

I like [JellyfiSSH](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jellyfissh/id416399476?mt=12) - I've just emailed the kiwi dude that writes it & asked for an option to open new connections in a new tab rather than opening a window for every single connection.  Otherwise I like it.  Mind you I paid my $4 or whatever it was just to try it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! Your software recommendation would be vastly more useful if you included a link to it. Also, some reasons why you would recommend it (beyond “I like it”), maybe even a short listing of pros and cons, would help the OP to make up his own mind about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have, and continue to recommend [JellyFiSSH](http://www.grepsoft.net/jellyfissh.html). But my tone has changed a tad. It used to be free, and it's a very simple, very helpful application. Visual creation of tunnels not terribly unlike PuTTY, and lots of other SSH tweaking capability.

However, it's no longer free. It's now USD$3 on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jellyfissh/id416399476?mt=12). Which is by no means a large amount of money, but admittedly kind of unfortunate for users.

Still, it's a wonderful application, and at least 6 of my co-workers swear by it. (And another 3 know the options to pass on the command line, or put into their `~/.ssh/config` file.)

Answer (score 0):

Since your *free* requirement is "preferably", I'd go ahead and recommend a paid one (and rather expensive if you ask me):

A very good App under Windows, now ported to other platforms. [SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/products/beta/securecrt/mac_osx.html).

<sub>*I do not work for SecureCRT and have nothing to do with it. I used it at an old job.*</sub>